# Guardar datos en array en PHP y mostrarlo

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código y quisiera que me fuera guardando los datos en un `array` para luego mostrarlos al darle al botón mostrar.

¿Alguien sabe como hacer un `array` que guarde los datos introducidos en las variables nombre y apellido?

```
<?php 
    //Declaro los textos que van a usar los botones de los submits
    const GUARDAR = 'Guardar';
    const VER_DATOS = 'Ver datos';
    //Inicializo las variables que contienen los valores de los inputs a null en caso de que no se haya enviado el formulario aún
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];


$datos = array("nombre" => $nombre, "apellido" => $apellido);
    //Si el metodo de la solicitud es un post es decir si se envio el formulario y la operacion tiene algun valor
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['operacion'])){
      //Si la operacion es la de guardar.....
      if($_POST['operacion'] === GUARDAR){
          //Abro el archivo para escribir
          $file = @fopen("datos.txt", "w");
          //Creo un arreglo con los valores que voy a guardar
          $data = ['nombre' => $nombre, 'apellido' => $apellido];            
          //Guardo el arreglo codificado a json
          fwrite($file, json_encode($data));
          //Cierro el archivo
          fclose($file);

          $nombre = null;
          $apellido = null;
      } else {
          //Si la operacion es la de Cargar o ver y el archivo existe
          if(file_exists('datos.txt')){
              //Almaceno el contenido completo del archivo en esta variable
              $content = file_get_contents('datos.txt');
              //Decodifico el contenido almacenado en formato json
              $decoded = json_decode($content);
              //Asigno los valores traidos del archivo
             $nombre = $decoded->nombre;
             $apellido = $decoded->apellido;

          }
      }
    }



    //Cuerpo de la página
    $body = '
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Formulario</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
        </head>

        <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <FORM method="post" name="formulario" autocomplete="off">
        Nombre:<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="'.$nombre.'">

        Apellido: <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" value="'.$apellido.'">

        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="'.GUARDAR.'" name="operacion">
        <input type="submit" value="'.VER_DATOS.'" name="operacion">

        </FORM>
        </body>
        </html>';

    echo $body;
    echo $nombre." ".$apellido;
    ?>
```

Comment: Puedes hacer algo como esto: `$arrPersona=array("nombre"=>$nombre, "apellido"=>$apellido);` para probar el array: `var_dump($arrPersona);` Pero, veo que tienes algo similar aquí: `$data = ['nombre' => $nombre, 'apellido' => $apellido]; `,  no entiendo entonces cuál es el problema... Si es para guardar varias personas, por ejemplo en un bucle, pones `[]` delante de la variable: `$arrPersona[]=array("nombre"=>$nombre, "apellido"=>$apellido); para probar el array: var_dump($arrPersona);`

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, por favor edita tu pregunta, tiene serios problemas de formato y así es muy dificil poder ayudarte. Haz clic [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/205402/edit) para editar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para crear un array con esos varolees puedes hacer esto:

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$datos = array("nombre" => $nombre, "apellido" => $apellido);
```

Como veras **$datos** es un **array** con los indices **nombre** y **apellido** y para obtener sus datos nuevamente puedes hacer esto:

```
<?php 

$nombre = $datos["nombre"];
$apellido = $datos["apellido"];

echo $nombre." ".$apellido;

?>
```

para ver que varoles e indices tiene el array puedes hacer:

```
<?php

print_r($datos);

ó

var_dump($datos);

?>
```

Comment: tengo este código, pero no consigo que al pulsar el botón guardar datos me muestre todos los nombres y apellidos que he introducido a través del formulario. ¿ Alguna solución?

Comment: Tienes que colocar lo que tienes en javascript para poder darte una solución completa, es decir tienes que colocar el código js y el php para ver cuando haces el evento click para visualizar los nombres y apellidos

Comment: Todo el código está arriba puesto

Comment: Dudo que la respuesta resuelva el problema dado que ni la pregunta tiene el formato minimo requerido para el sitio. Por tu puntaje veo que ya tienes bastantante idea de cómo funciona esto, deberias esperar a que OP mejore la calidad de su pregunta