# guardar datos en un array y mostrarlos en un tabla

Tags: php, html, array, html-tabla

estoy intentando hacer un pequeño formulario con PHP y HTML donde tengo un select llamado 'padecimientos' que se llena con ajax, quiero que al seleccionar un padecimiento y hacer click en un input se guarde en un array el 'idPadecimiento' y el 'nombre'. Mi idea es que guarde varios objetos en el array y los muestre en una tabla para posteriormente guardar el array en la base de datos cuando ya haya seleccionado todos los padecimientos esto por medio de un segundo botón.

Encontre un ejemplo algo parecido a mi idea en el siguiente link.
[Guardar datos en array en PHP y mostrarlo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/205402/guardar-datos-en-array-en-php-y-mostrarlo)

Pero solo guarda un objeto y quiero que guarde mas de uno alguien me podria ayudar por favor, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías consultar la documentación oficial de PHP:

[array-push](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php)

```
<?php
  $pila = array("naranja", "plátano");
  array_push($pila, "manzana", "arándano");
  print_r($pila);
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!. Fue de mucha ayuda.